# Creating UNDO function for all queries run towards a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am running a lean startup. While we have good safety against hardware failures, we often need to manipulate customer data by running SQL queries directly on the live database. It is so easy to make mistakes (like thinking that you are running a delete query on the test database, while you were actually running the query directly on the live database). I am wondering if there are something I can do to create "undo" functionality for every SQL query that is run against the database (also if someone connects directly via PSQL). I do not care about performance, nor storage space as secure data is my only concern.

It would be excellent if the UNDO function had the possibility to not undo some specific transactions in the transaction log, so going backwards would not interfere with correct transactions, like new customers signing up. We have very low volumes of such transactions so they can be looked through manually without problem.

Comment: oh well, either buy "better" (ha, holy flamewar potential here) databases ( Oracle for example supports this as "flashback" since version 10) or try out the old timetravel postgre feature http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/contrib-spi.html ( F.27.2. ). Its not standard any more but emulateable as described here https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/spi/timetravel.example

Comment: This seems to require that I modify the table by adding the  price_on abstime,
price_off abstime columns. I was expecting this to work for any query including "delete from table;"

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the only option you have is to create a history table.
I've done this with the help of triggers.

At every update you insert one row for every value that changed.

My history table look like this (MySql):

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `id_history` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,      
  `event` ENUM('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE') NOT NULL ,
  `table` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `field` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `old_value` TEXT NULL ,
  `datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_history`);
```

And the trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER test_table_update BEFORE UPDATE ON test_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF OLD.value1 != NEW.value1 THEN
            INSERT INTO history VALUES(NULL, 'UPDATE', 'test_table', OLD.id_test_table, 'value1', OLD.value1, NOW());
        END IF;

        ...

    END; //
```

With this information you can undo every change and also set it back to a specific date.

Comment: This seems like a solution that would solve my problem. I wonder whether anything like this exists in a framework for PostgreSQL, there must be so many others with the same need.

Comment: google was so kind to find: http://pgxn.org/dist/e-maj/ - but no experience... using builtin flashback engine since... well since it existed ;-) - earlier, we were of the great idea... if you commit a transaction you are sure of it :-D

Comment: @David: there are some solutions: https://github.com/willowtreeapps/postgres-history-tables and this: https://github.com/imincik/pghistory-tracker and this: http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/

Comment: @David - "there must be so many others with the same need" - most people, if they've encountered issues as you originally described a few times tend to change permissions around so that the devs can't accidentally access the production database in the first place.